# How can I insert a date from a text box into a query in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a textbox in a form where I am entering dates.

Normally in a query built in MS Access query designer the date is written like: #mm/dd/yyyy#

If I would like to take the date input from a textbox I have in a form why can't I just write: #Forms!ExampleForm!dateText# ?

Comment: Assume you are building query object. The query engine should recognize textbox input as a date value and therefore # delimiters not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Specify it as a *parameter*:

```
Parameters [Forms]![ExampleForm]![dateText] DateTime;
Select * From YourTable
Where [YourDateField] = [Forms]![ExampleForm]![dateText]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, enter a date in textbox.  Then open sql window and execute below lines separately

`Select #Forms!ExampleForm!dateText#` 
`Select Forms!ExampleForm!dateText`

The first line will give you syntax error as access database engine can't figure out the value where as second line will return the textbox date.

In where clause dates must be enclosed in # signs but not the control name.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted your question about outputting a variable in a string in your C++ program about voting, while I was in the middle of writing up the solution. Don't do this, it's like the users that post for help on a forum and then only respond with "figured it out" and don't post the solution for anyone showing up from googling the same issue, etc., to benefit from.